# JW player repeat not working?

Tags: servlets, jwplayer, jwplayer6

i have a servlet which streams an mp4 video

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    File file = new File("D:\\Software\\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\\bin\\vid\\testMp4.mp4");
    response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());
    ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[320652];
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    System.out.println("file sent");
}
```

and i have a a page to play this video with JW Player

```
<script>
        //alert(window.location.pathname);
        //alert(window.location.);
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            width: 520,
            height: 440,
            type:'mp4',
            file: 'http://localhost:8080/WorldCupWeb/getVid',
            tracks: [{
                        file: 'http://localhost:8080/WorldCupWeb/getVid' + '.vtt',
                        kind: 'thumbnails'
                    }]
        });
    </script>
```

The video plays without a problem , but when i press replay it wont replay the video or even call the Servlet again. instead it just keep showing the loading icon , what is wrong here ? help me please

Comment: i even tried removing the tracks option , but still the same :(

Comment: Just a guess here. I know nothing about jwplayer. But I assume in order to repeat it will need the video file to have been cached. So maybe adding some cache header to the servlet to cache for a certain time will help.

Comment: you mean a link to the servlet ? no its just in development in localhost.

Comment: ok ill try adding cache headers :D

Comment: I mean a link to a public page?